# Linux for a laptop, docking station, and 3 monitors

Tags: linux, laptop, multiple-monitors

I'm looking for suggestions on a Linux setup that will work well for a Dell Precision M4800 that has nVidia graphics and spends a large chunk of it's time on one of Dell's port replicator / docking station setups. The dock has a pair of monitors attached to it via DVI and a third attached via a [SIIG USB 3 adapter](http://www.siig.com/usb-3-0-to-hdmi-dvi-dual-head-display-adapter.html). It also uses a mouse from Logitec that utilizes their unifying receiver.

I need something that will work as well on my dock with 3 monitors as it will running on battery and using wifi out and about. I use CentOS & Red Hat at work every day (though mostly via the command line) and am quite familiar with Ubuntu, Mint, and Debian but have also utilized a variety of other distros including Gentoo, OpenSUSE, and Fedora so am pretty open when it comes to which to use.

My biggest request in this revolves around needing help making all this play well together in a way that wont leave me just saying the heck with it and returning to Windows.  Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: Best way to find out is to try it out. Your setup is pretty specific so I don't think there would be many people out there with a similar setup.

Comment: If nothing else, I'm hoping people have answers to at least parts of my setup. I have tried several things but hope I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I'd be posting questions on what **doesn't** work then, rather than asking this rather broad question.

Comment: Lol, this is what doesn't work, which is sad. Triple monitor setup, no go. Logitech mouse, no go (at least with RHEL 7). transitioning from docked to undocked, not elegant. Hence the big q.

Comment: Ok, well let's tackle the things one at a time, otherwise this question will get too cluttered. I'd delete this question and ask separate questions for the Triple Monitor setup, and Logitech Mouse.

Comment: @GeneBean Just out of curiosity, have you figured this out?

Comment: I gave up as nothing was working @Venemo. I've since heard that Ubuntu can support the USB3 adapters so maybe I'll try again.